# Java Sleep not working in loop

Tags: java, swing, sleep, event-dispatch-thread

What I want to do in  my java program is, that when I press the button it displays text in `textfield` in intervals of time.
i.e I press the button then a `jFrame` pops up and there is a label which shows text like:
1st second:"1st"
then a time lag of say 1 sec
then 2nd thing: "2nd"

I am a newbie and I tried to Google this problem but I couldn't find a solution even after 3-4 hours
I tried a lot of things: sleep, try n catch...

Please write the answer very simplified.

Here is my code: 
In the following code, when the button is pressed, the jFrame comes but has a white screen in it and when the sum ends, its screen turns grey and it shows the answer....

```
   private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    See.setVisible(true);//See is the JFrame   
    t007.setVisible(true);//Label in See
    l2.setVisible(true);//TextField in See
    int ran, g, d, col, ran2;
    double y = 1000 * (Double.parseDouble(t2.getText()));
    int x = (int) y;
    d = 0;
    double c = Math.pow(10, Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()));
    col = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
    for (g = 0; g < col;) {
        ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); // Random Number Creation Starts
        if (ran > (c / 10)) {
            g = g + 1;
            ran2 = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) % 2;
            if (ran2 == 1) {
                ran = ran * (-1);
            }
            d = d + ran;
            if (d < 0) {
                ran = ran * (-1);
                d = d + (2 * ran);
            }
            l2.setVisible(true);
            t007.setText("" + ran);
            System.out.println("" + ran);
            jButton6.doClick();
            //Pausing (Sleep)
            try {
                  Thread.sleep(x);

             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            }
            }
             l2.setText("" + d);
               }
```

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker` to provide background processing and synchronisation to back to the event queue.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: HEY GUYS, i cant understand u ppl, can u please talk simple and write the CODE and then tell me what and how.    PLEASE

Comment: @DakshShah Pay us first ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework, that is, all interactions and modifications to the UI are expected to occur within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The EDT is responsible for, amongst other things, processing repaint requests.

Anything that stops the EDT from running (like `Thread.sleep` and looping for a long time) will prevent it from processing the events, virtually "hanging" your application until it becomes unblocked...

Now, I tried to decipher what you program was trying to do...but failed, so instead...I made a pretty counter...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TickOver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TickOver();
    }

    public TickOver() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JButton button;
        private int tick; 
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {

            field = new JTextField(10);
            field.setEditable(false);
            button = new JButton("Start");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    tick = 0;
                    timer.start();
                }
            });

            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    field.setText(Integer.toString(++tick));
                    if (tick > 4) {
                        timer.stop();
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(field, gbc);
            add(button, gbc);

        }
    }
}
```

Take a close look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details...

Comment: hi, i want this thing but i dont have much idea how to add this in my program

Comment: I dont know how to create a class and what does main do

Comment: in my code main had automatically some code and i have no idea how to put this code in that; how to create the classes n all

Comment: Please Help, @madprogrammer

Comment: Start by taking a closer look [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/), in fact, reading the entire tutorial would be of use to you.

Comment: IT would be wonderful if u could tell me what to code in the button, pls pls pls help

Comment: ???????????????can u tell me what to code in button????? @madprogrammer

Comment: It would be wonderful if you would take the time learn the required basics of language. The Timer is in essence doing the job of the loop.  But you will have to allow for the break in local variable context...

Comment: hey, i cant understand what u are saying, " break in local variable context" and all.
i m reading the page u asked me to read 
but i was hoping that u could tell me how to intergate the progrms

THANKS FOR HELPING ME

Comment: i read that page, still no idea how to do it

Man, i m sorry but if u can help me by making it simpler pls do

Thanks a lot

Comment: The example I've provided is as simple as it's going to get. The Timer is acting like loop. Within in the adtionPerformed method, you need to test for your exit condition (g >= col) and stop the timer when it's meet. The content of the loop needs to sit within the else condition. You will need to take into account, that each time the timer triggers, any local variables will be reset, so you will need to alter their context/visibility, probably making them instance variables. Don't forget to initialise them before you start the timer

Answer (score 1):

You should ***never sleep*** in UI thread, as it make the *UI lag*. As if the process takes time to complete the UI will get stuck and user experience will get hurt.

Use other mechanisms such as a `Timer` or `SwingWorker`

[Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @DakshShah The comments already contain the links for helping you to get started. Read those and ask if you still have problem. I will add that link too.

Comment: What is a thread, what is UI, and how to integrate timer or swing worker in my program

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad practice to sleep the user interface thread. (As this will cause the application to become unresponsive.) You ought to put all this code inside the `Run()` method of a `Runnable` instance:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Your code here.
            }
        });
```

Comment: If he sleeps in the runnable it won't make a difference, you run it on the EDT too...

Comment: Where should i put all this, as i told u i m totally a newbie

Comment: I use netbeans and i just code on buttons and all but not like this and how how how please explain

Comment: A `SwingWorker` would be a more suitable solution as it provides handy methods for resyncing updates back into the EDT - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you run your long running loop on the event dispatch thread. But this is the thread that must dispatch all events of the application like mouse or keyboard events but also repaint events that causes your user interface to get repainted every time it gets 'dirty'. That means, while your for-loop is running, the user interface is not repainted nor are any other events processed. Your UI freezes!
Your jButton5ActionPerformed method should return as soon as possible so that the event dispatch thread can process other events. Your long running operation should be run by a separate thread in the background.

A good starting point is the following tutorial about concurrency in Swing:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Maybe you can use the SwingWorker class to perform your background work:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html